# Utlizar SMO no SSMS

Tags: sql-server

É possível utilizar *SMO* substituta do *SQLDMO* dentro do *SSMS* (Versão SQL Server 2008 R2)? Usar funções como listar instâncias dentro da rede similar a `ListAvailableSQlServers()` do  SQLDMO?

Answer (score 1):

### É possível utilizar SMO substituta do SQLDMO dentro do SSMS (Versão SQL Server 2008 R2)?

[Segundo o Technet, o recurso SQLDMO foi removido do SQL Server 2012 em diante](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131540%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). O recurso SMO foi mantido. Entretanto, você deve usá-lo ou por Powershell ou por algum aplicativo escrito no Visual Studio. A função do SSMS é outra.

### Usar funções como listar instâncias dentro da rede similar a `ListAvailableSQlServers()` do SQLDMO?

A ideia é que todo o suporte que existia usando o SQLDMO seja transferido para o Powershell. `ListAvailableSQLServers` pode ser reescrita como:

```
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.Filter = ("computer")
$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name")
$Computers = $objSearcher.FindAll()
foreach ($machine_name in  $Computers | sort computername )
{
    $sql_servers = get-wmiobject -class win32_service -computer $machine_name
    $sql_servers | where { $_.name -like 'MSSQL$' -or $_.name -eq 'MSSQLSERVER'} | select name
}
```

[Tirei este script daqui](http://sqlvariant.com/2010/09/finding-sql-servers-with-powershell/).

Comment: Valeu Cigano, terei realmente que fazer "algumas" mudanças kkkkkk. Tinha alguns códigos muito úteis... mas...... da uma olhada nesse: